# Flutter scaffold of context giving "does not contain a Scaffold"

Tags: flutter

I have an appbar in a scaffold.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: styling.appBar(
      AppBar(
        leading: styling.iconButton(() => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), Icons.menu),
      )
  ),
);
```

This is the iconButton:

```
  ClipRRect iconButton(VoidCallback onPressed, IconData icon) {
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(360),
  child : Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          icon,
          color: secondaryColor,
        ),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      )
  ),
);
```

}

This is to replace the default hamburger icon that opens the drawer, when I click it I get this error:

```
Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
```

Comment: because the `BuildContext` that is passed to your `build` method doesn't contain `Scaffold`. Try wrapping your leading widget inside `Builder`.

Comment: thank you bro you are the bread of my life

Comment: @iaminpainpleasehelp1 - a full explanation and possible workaround is detailed below

Answer (score 12):

This almost certainly because your `context` is ACTUALLY outside of a Scaffold. Your function probably looks something similar to this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ... other code up here

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: styling.appBar(AppBar(
      leading: styling.iconButton(() => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), Icons.menu),
    )),
  );
}
```

The problem here is that `context` actually DID come from a place that is not inside the Scaffold. The `context` that you are using here is from the function parameter of the wrapping `build()` function, which does exist outside of the Scaffold (because this `build()` is what is actually generating the `Scaffold`).

What you need to do is something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // ... other code up here

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: styling.appBar(
      AppBar(
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return styling.iconButton(() => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(), Icons.menu);
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Or something similar. The reason is because now, inside the `builder` function, you actually have a new `context` object, which WILL actually exist inside the Scaffold.

Hopefully that is clear. If not, I can explain further.

Answer (score -1):

Edit 1: simple solution

```
Builder(
  builder: (context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Drawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: according to the docs, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html, global keys are expensive. you should use them sparingly. in this case, the problem can easily be solved by using a Builder, which is far less expensive. in this case global keys are not the best solution, though sometimes they are for sure

Comment: @loushou, the fact that the previous alternative was expensive has no relation with it being a valid answer. The only thing worth noting is what you added.

Comment: @Storo if following the guidelines outlined by the Flutter team, creators and maintainers of the Flutter Framework, have no relevance on a correct answer for a question about the Flutter Framework, then you are right... it makes no difference. But if you want to participate in the community, and use the tech the way it was intended, then it is completely relevant. your call really. take the advice or leave it. matters not to me.